# How do I take the derivative of integral with respect to a function?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals, machine-learning

I am reading this [lecture note](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf) about Variational Inference. It is optimizing the ELBO by mean field factorization and coordinate ascent. However, I cannot understand how the formula $(23)$ is derived from $(22)$.

$$\tag{22}
L_{k} = \int q(z_{k})E_{-k}[\log  p(z_{k}|z_{-k},x)] \,dz_{k} -   \int q(z_{k})\log q(z_{k}) \,dz_{k} 
$$
Take the derivative with respect to $q(z_{k})$
$$\tag{23}
\frac{dL_{k}}{dq(z_{k})} = E_{-k}[\log  p(z_{k}|z_{-k},x)] -   \log  q(z_{k})  -  1 = 0 
$$
how does it take the derivative of the integral $(23)$ with respect to $q(z_{k})$?

Comment: [Functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for the comment. I thought there was some easier way to look at it because I haven't learned functional.